# How does a rodless electrical linear actuator work?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, linear-motors

I want to pull some weight horizontally and for that i have settled for a linear actuator.

[image]

The actuator should pull some weight as it moves back and forth as the gif shows.

There are linear actuators i could find but they are too bulky with heavy motors and a lot of lubrication and the noise they make is not music to my ears.

I found electrical actuators to be a perfect fit but i do not know how they work for instance this actuator: [R4 Series](http://www.kollmorgen.com/en-us/products/linear-actuators/rodless-actuators/r4-series/)

Comment: Look into ultrasonic motors. I don't know if there are any in trade for such "generic application" but they can be entirely silent, very compact and provide surprising amount of force for their size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found these images. Looks like they are driven by a motor.

**Belt Driven Model**

[image: Belt Driven Model]

**Screw Driven Model**

[image]

I suggest reviewing [this](http://www.kollmorgen.com/en-us/products/linear-actuators/rodless-actuators/r4-series/_literature/r3-r4_drive-shaft-installation_en-us_reva/) document

Answer (score 2):

For a minimum of moving parts, you can get linear stepper motors. With the right kind of controller (microstepping), the motion can be very smooth and quiet.

For example, I have in the past worked with linear actuators from [Nippon Pulse](http://www.nipponpulse.com/), driven by a motor controller from [Technosoft](http://www.technosoftmotion.com/en/). Very precise and powerful, but also very expensive!

Comment: Dave just out of interest, how much roughly would we be talking for the smallest linear servormotor from Nippon Pulse?

Comment: @user88720: I didn't do the purchasing, so I'm not too sure. We used a couple of medium-sized dual-rail ones (500 mm travel) that I believe cost somewhere in the neighborhood of $2500 each. Way too costly for our end application, but we wanted the precision and the ability to experiment with different algorithms in our research prototypes.

Comment: Fair enough. When I noticed they had a precision down to the nanometer, I got the feeling they were going to be pretty expensive. Too expensive for my application as well :(